# How to insert a row with one column value equal to an array using node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am new to node-postgres and I want to insert a row in a table using [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg), where one column value is an array of strings and one an array of integers.

Earlier I used to use sequelize and now I am not using any ORMS, want to use the native library for postgres in Node.

```
let names =['abc', 'qwe', 'aaa'];
let type = [2, 3, 4, 5];

let query = 'INSERT INTO  sample(names, type) VALUES ($1, $2)' ;
db.query(query, [names, type], (err, res) => {
   if (err) {
   return (err)
 }
 return res.send(res.rows[0])
})
```

I am thrown an error invalid syntax near "["

Comment: You want raw query ?

Comment: @RameshS yes, I want a raw query using stored proceudres/parameterized query

Comment: Use sequelize ORM it is better then raw query

Comment: If these are `text` fields, you can do `JSON.stringify` and store the output. If I understood your question correctly...

Comment: if you are using raw query then make it as per insert format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990186/how-do-i-properly-insert-multiple-rows-into-pg-with-node-postgres

Comment: @RameshS, ORMs cause a performance lag when dealing with large scale of data because ORMs first manipulate the query and then the query is executed which takes a bit of time which is crucial when dealing with large scale of data.

Comment: For the fastest and most scalable approach, see [multi-row inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).