# How do I make a PG SQL ilike query in Javascript injection safe?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sql-injection

I want to have a simple search box in my web application using Javascript/Node.js and Postgresql. In it I have a form which is open for the public to make searches for names. I am not using any ORM so how do I make this type of search query safe in the backend, while using `.then()` ?

I want to use sort of `SELECT * FROM spotters WHERE last_name ilike '%Burns%'` but safely. The code below doesn't work, but how can I solve this? It feels like it should be quite easy.

```
// req.query.name = 'Burns' --- Could be "';DROP TABLE"!
pg_client.query("SELECT * FROM spotters WHERE last_name ilike '%?%'", [req.query.name])
  .then((sqlResult) => {
// handle result
  })
```

I want to have code similar to the above where it can ilike-search for column last name with a query received from the search input.

Comment: Just a thought but won't it work if you put % round req.query.name and then bind that string so your prepared statement is just normal `where last_name ilike ?`

Comment: No, that doesn't work either unfortunately

Comment: *Obviously*, it does

Comment: In that case, I would like to understand exactly how that code would look because I cannot make it work.

Comment: @Christoffer I found a better answer in a different thread so I deleted my answer below.  Have a look:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174695/prevent-sql-injection-with-nodejs-and-postgres  This answer wraps the solution in an async function, which is nicer.  You're very close.

Comment: Thanks! That's very close to get what I need. For some reason using '?' does not work but $1 does. Now I just need to understand how to get the % around the $1 so that it works.

Comment: I solved this by declaring the query variable as name = '%' + query + '%'