# Insert multiple values into a column of a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres, node-pg-pool

Suppose I want to insert multiple rows into a table in PostregSQL. The example below shows how to do that using only one row, but what if I want to insert several rows? How to do that? If I have several names with the same email?

```
const text = 'INSERT INTO users(name, email) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING *'
const values = ['brianc', 'brian.m.carlson@gmail.com']

// promise
client
  .query(text, values)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.rows[0])
    // { name: 'brianc', email: 'brian.m.carlson@gmail.com' }
  })
  .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

Comment: are you looking for a js solution, or a postgres solution? in postgres, it is simply, `insert into users(name, email) values('foo', 'foo@email.com') ('bar', 'bar@email.com'), ('qux', 'qux@email.com')`.

Comment: well actually i'm looking for a js solution where i could insert several rows of values without bloating the request for readability. thanks!

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990186/how-do-i-properly-insert-multiple-rows-into-pg-with-node-postgres) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly insert multiple rows into PG with node-postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990186/how-do-i-properly-insert-multiple-rows-into-pg-with-node-postgres)

Comment: @marmeladze yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, `pg-format` is great. will be great if you want to post it as an answer, so I can accept it! thank you for your help!