# Passing VALUES clause as query parameter

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to refactor the existing code fragments that use postgresql `pg`  module, and look like this:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO jobs (title, type, label) VALUES ${stringValues}`;
        let { rows } = await pg.query(sql, []);
```

Here they have `VALUES` clause as a calculated `stringValues` string that looks like this:

```
"('title1', 'type1', 'label1'),('title2', 'type2', 'label2')"
```

I was trying to make this fragment more injection-safe and elegant, to pass parameters via $1. I have tried `VALUES array[$1]` with passing `[stringValues.split(',')]` as $1 - no luck.
Also tried `VALUES array[$1::record]` , `(SELECT array[$1::record])`, various jsonb_ conversions, etc - still no luck.

Could anybody please advise any good way to pass such parameters for insert VALUES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way for a relatively small amount of data is using the pg-format library. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63167970/878272) from a similar question and [this github issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/957#issuecomment-200000070) for reference.

```js
import format from "pg-format";

const values = [['title1', 'type1', 'label1'],['title2', 'type2', 'label2']]
const sql = `INSERT INTO jobs (title, type, label) VALUES %L`
const {rows} = await pg.query(format(sql,values))
```

If you are bulk loading large amounts of data. it might be worth considering using the [`COPY FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command functionality implemented in [pg-copy-streams](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams#pipe-from-a-file-to-table-copyin---copy-from) which will be much more performant.